# Solve $2x^2y'y'' - xy'' + y' =0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm solving the differential equation $2x^2y'y'' - xy'' + y' =0$

Can someone verify whether I'm correct?

My attempt:

We let $z = y'$

The differential equation becomes:

$$2x^2zz' - xz' + z = 0$$

$$\Rightarrow 2x^2z\frac{dz}{dx} - x\frac{dz}{dx} + z = 0$$
$$\Rightarrow  -x + z\frac{dx}{dz} = -2x^2z$$

This is a Bernouilli equation in $x$.

Let's substitute $u = 1/x, du/dz =-1/x^2dx/dz$ which yields:

$$z\frac{du}{dz} +u = 2z$$

This is a first order linear differential equation, which has the solution (after separation of variables)

$$u =c_1(z-2)$$

or

$$\frac{1}{x} = c_1(y'-2)$$

and equivalently:

$$y' = 2 + \frac{1}{c_1x}$$

and after integration:

$$y = \frac{1}{c_1}\ln|c_1x| + 2x + c_2$$

I'm asking to verify this because the solution in my book says the solution should be

$$1/2\ln|x| \pm 1/2 \sqrt{1_4c_1x^2} \mp 1/2\ln(1 + \sqrt{1-4c_1x^2}) \pm 1/2\ln(2\sqrt{|c_1|x} + c_2)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution you obtained from $z\frac{du}{dz}+u=2z$ is incorrect. If you substitute $1=\frac{d}{dz}(z)$, then you should obtain:
$$z\frac{du}{dz}+\frac{d}{dz}(z)\cdot u=2z$$
Therefore, we can now apply the reverse product rule:
$$\frac{d}{dz}(zu)=2z$$
After integrating both sides with respect to $z$, this gives:
$$u=z+\frac{C}{z}$$

---

Substituting back, you should obtain:
$$\frac{1}{x}=y'+\frac{C}{y'}$$
$$\frac{1}{x}=\frac{(y')^2+C}{y'}$$
$$x((y')^2+C)=y'$$
$$x(y')^2+Cx=y'$$
$$x(y')^2-y'+Cx=0$$
You can now solve for $y'$ using the quadratic formula and then you should obtain the suggested solution after integrating both sides with respect to $x$.

Comment: Wow nice trick with the product. Didn't see that one yet.

Comment: Well, that trick is essentially what is done when solving 1st order linear nonhomogeneous ODE's using integrating factors.